# Why do hardhat tests pass on localhost network but fails on rinkeby network

Tags: javascript, evm, ethers.js, testrpc, hardhat

My tests run perfectly on localhost but fail when i set the network to rinkeby.

**Function that causes error**

```
uint256 public deadline = block.timestamp + 30 seconds;
function timeLeft() public view returns (uint256) {
        if (block.timestamp >= deadline) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return deadline - block.timestamp;
        }
    }
```

**The test**

```
console.log('\t'," ⌛️ fast forward time...")
await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [3600])
await network.provider.send("evm_mine")

const timeLeft2 = await stakerContract.timeLeft()
console.log('\t',"⏱ Time should be up now: ",timeLeft2.toNumber())
expect(timeLeft2.toNumber()).to.equal(0);
```

**The error**

```
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x6F27719c44460EEAea3005BC8CAd84508582B911","to":"0x784196D6a72C9d526cD5b45e3F23057B1aC4d0B4","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0de0b6b3a7640000"},"data":"0x3a4b66f1","accessList":null}, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.4.3)
```

Comment: The test have unlimited funds, how much etc do you have on rinkerby?

Comment: I have about 1 rinkeby Eth on the contract address and on the deployers address. The test now seems to run properly for some unknown reason.Thank you